# Missed header file onnx-ml.pb.h

Tags: ubuntu, openvino

I trying to compile OpenVINO from sources for release 2021-3

I've faced with issue:

```
~/Projects/OpenVINO/cmake-build-debug/_deps/ext_onnx-src/onnx/onnx_pb.h:50:10: fatal error: onnx/onnx-ml.pb.h: No such file or directory
     #include "onnx/onnx-ml.pb.h"
```

I use the following options:

```
cmake -DVERBOSE_BUILD=ON -DENABLE_TEMPLATE_PLUGIN=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DENABLE_PYTHON=ON -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/python3 -DENABLE_WHEEL=ON -DENABLE_TESTS=ON -DENABLE_FASTER_BUILD=ON -DONNX_ML=1 -DIE_EXTRA_MODULES=${OPENVINO_CONTRIB_REPO_DIR}/modules -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" ~/Projects/OpenVINO
```

Also this header file is absent in `~/Projects/OpenVINO/cmake-build-debug/_deps/ext_onnx-src/onnx/` ...

Seems like `onnx` should be compiled during build time in directory `~/Projects/OpenVINO/cmake-build-debug/_deps/ext_onnx-src` ...

Maybe I've missed some option ?

Comment: Did you see the following issue https://github.com/onnx/onnx/issues/1947 ? It looks to be related to the error you are experiencing

Comment: @jwalton I saw it and it help, but only in case when I compile onnx separately, but as you can see onnx is provided in cmake-build directory with sources for building

Comment: I mean it should work without compiling onnx separatly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is recommended for you to use the latest OpenVINO version 2021.3 and refer to the wiki section from the link I provide below.

Build the OpenVINO from source correctly according to your OS [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/wiki)

Make sure you could successfully build it (means all pre-requisite had been installed & setup correctly)

I had attached in the mentioned thread below, the snapshot of successfully built from source of OpenVINO 2021.3  & I'm using Ubuntu 18.04

My steps are the same as this guide: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino/wiki/BuildingForLinux

NOTE: make sure you are using CMake* 3.13 or higher

Fyi,  this question is similar to [this thread](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/Missed-header-file-onnx-onnx-ml-pb-h/m-p/1273559#M23515).

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable faster build by setting -DENABLE_FASTER_BUILD=OFF. I had a similar problem and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Building the onyx_proto project showed that my python path was not correct.  Since python is needed to generate the header files, you may need to set this correctly in the cmake setup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).